# actionscript 3 load URL from array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, url

I'm making a mp3/steaming radio with MVC, where I'm trying to load an URL from a array.

I have a radio class:

```
public class Radio
{
    private var titel:String;
    private var url:URLRequest;
    private var cover:Bitmap;

    public function Radio(titel:String, url:URLRequest, cover:Bitmap)
    {
        this.titel = titel;
        this.url = url;
        this.cover = cover;
    }

    public function getTitel():String {
        return titel;
    }

    public function getURL():URLRequest {
        return url;
    }

    public function getCover():Bitmap {
        return cover

    }
}
```

In the controller i have this:

```
public function selectRadio(radio:Radio):void{

        model.selectRadio(radio);
    }
```

In view I have the button with the eventlistner:

```
radio.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function():void {
            controller.selectRadio(model.getRadio(0));
        });
```

And finally in the model i have:

```
private var radio:Radio = new Radio("P3", new URLRequest("http://live-icy.gss.dr.dk:80/A/A05L.mp3"), drp3);

private var radioArray:Array = new Array(radio);
    private var r:Number;

public function selectRadio(radio:Radio):void {

        var s:Sound = new Sound();  
        var chan:SoundChannel = s.play();

        s.load();

        trace("radio");
    }

    public function getRadios():Array {
        return radioArray;

        trace("All radio channels collected");
    }

    public function getRadio(radioNumber:int):Radio {
        r = radioNumber;
        return radioArray[radioNumber];

        trace("Actual radio collected");
    }
```

The problem is in the selectRadio function. I don't know how to load the URL in the arrays. It should be s.load(--something in here--); The reason why I'm doing this, is because I want to have multiple radio stations.

Hope you can help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var s:Sound = new Sound(radio.getURL());
var chan:SoundChannel = s.play();
```

load function will be called automatically by the constructor, also don't forget to stop previous SoundChannel.

and here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html you will find everything about Sound

Comment: Oh btw, do you know to make the stream only play once? If i press it more than once, it plays two stream on top of each other. I've tried an if statement with s.close(), but that didn't work.

Comment: As I already written you need to stop previous SoundChannel before playing new Sound. So you need to keep reference (ex. in a private property) to currently used SoundChannel and call `soundChannel.stop()` right before playing new Sound.